# How do you combine First, Previous, Numeric, Next and Last in Gridview (ASP.net)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview, custompaging

We know that the pagerSetting Mode of the gridview has NextPrevious, NextPreviousFirstLast, Numeric and NumericFirstLast. But how can I have it like this:

> << Previous     < First   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Next >  Last >>

Comment: Not exactly but.. https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Templates/Pager.aspx

Comment: Here u go http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20777/A-very-nice-and-complete-custom-GridView-pager or try googling https://www.google.com/search?q=gridview+custom+pager+template